# Associate a folder to an APK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-platform

In the app I was helping developing, the users seen that each time they use apps like CM Security to clean 'junk', the files inside the folder associated with the app were instead considered as 'junk' and are deleted.

The app itself would create the folder in the C side of the code instead of using Java.

Firstly, when the app is first launched, custom C code will check if the app folder (e.g. 'Game') exists. If it doesn't, it makes it (regardless of OS. The app is cross-platform, sorry I forgot to say it.) It puts it in the external SD card ('sdcard/'). When it's seen, it can now run the app.

I get about the `getFilesDir`, but since the directory is made using C code and not through the java activity, it doesn't count as its app directory.

Is there a way to link the folder to the Android code so that it would be recognized as the app folder?

Comment: `Context().getFilesDir()` is a folder associated to your app, i do not get your question Sir

Comment: That could be it, but what I'm asking is people were complaining that the junk cleaner apps are removing the files from the app folder created by the C code.

Now that I know that it could be done on code, I want to know how to link the folder created by C code to the Java code so that the app associates the folder as an app folder and junk cleaning apps would not remove the files inside it.

Comment: Isn't that just a naming convention? Create your folder in the correct place with the correct name. See also `Context.getFilesDir`.

Comment: Okay, I think I needed to make clear of something. I updated the question now to make it clearer.